# How to add dataURL image as source in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, layers, tiles, image

I am building a web application with OpenLayers that should have offline map support. I save pictures from a WMS server to the browser cache and load them from the cache as a dataURL. The next step is to input the dataURL to an tileWMS source in OpenLayers. When examining the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html) there seems to be an option called [**tileLoadFunction**](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.html#.TileLoadFunctionType) that should allow a dataURL to be passed in and added as the source. However I'm not able to understand how to use this option.

Does anyone know how to use the **tileLoadFunction** or know of some other way to input a dataURL as a source in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4213#issuecomment-145149625) that talked about how to input dataURL data to a layer.

I solved my problem by adding a custom tileLoadFunction.

```
const cacheSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    tileLoadFunction: function(imageTile, src) {
        var url = new URL(src);
        var bbox = url.searchParams.get("BBOX");
        var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();

        var key = zoom + "-" + bbox;

        if(cacheMode){
            imageTile.getImage().src = src;
            cacheTile(key, src);
        } 
        else if(!cacheMode){
            localforage.getItem(key, function(err, dataURL){
                imageTile.getImage().src = dataURL;
                console.log("Loaded Tile from cache: " + key);
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    },
    url: "http://your-wms-server.com",
    params: {
        'LAYERS': 'mapLayer'
    },

});
```

`src` is a url for a WMS call and `imageTile` is an `ol.ImageTile` who's source can be set to the url or a dataURL as can be seen in the [github issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4213#issuecomment-145149625).